# Automatic resizing of CircuitLab schematics

Tags: bug, circuitlab

I totally love the CircuitLab plug in, I really do. But this behavior is ... let's call it 'noteworthy'. Look at the circuit diagrams for series and parallel resistors, they're huge.

[Basic rules to calculate the equivalent resistance of a resistor circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60977/basic-rules-to-calculate-the-equivalent-resistance-of-a-resistor-circuit/60979#60979)

[image]

I propose to use a ×1 scale at max. Scaling down my turn into an issue too, rendering the circuit too small, but I've not come across one yet.

Comment: They are already working on that I believe.

Comment: Oh that would be really nice. The article looks so weird with these huge devices.

Comment: uh-oh ... didn't spot the duplicate question.

Comment: No kidding - they're just boxes too. Are they missing the link to the resistor symbol? ;)